# I want to make a link where the href is dependent on a js variable

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href, innerhtml

I figured out the whole innerhtml thing but I don't know how to add variables into the href. I want it to make a link with the title being the title you enter and with the javascript that you enter to be in the href when you click "create".

```html
<div class="title">
  Bookmarklet Maker
  <br>
  <br>
  <input size="13" onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);" name="getTitle" type="text" id="getTitle" style="background-color: #252525;  border: 2px;  border-style: double;  border-color: white;  color: white;  padding: 15px 32px;  text-align: left;  text-decoration: none;  display: inline-block;  font-size: 16px;  font-weight: bold;  margin: 4px 2px;  cursor:;"
    placeholder="Bookmarklet name" />
  <br>
  <input size="40" onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);" name="geJs" type="text" id="getJs" style="background-color: #252525;  border: 2px;  border-style: double;  border-color: white;  color: white;  padding: 15px 32px;  text-align: left;  text-decoration: none;  display: inline-block;  font-size: 16px;  font-weight: bold;  margin: 4px 2px;  cursor:;"
    placeholder="Javascript" />
  <br>
  <button style="background-color: #252525;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;" id="bookmarkletbutton" onclick="createBookmarklet()">Create</button>
  <script>
    function createBookmarklet() {
      var title_input = document.getElementById('getTitle').value;
      var js_input = document.getElementById('getJs').value;
      document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title_input;
      document.getElementById('js').innerHTML = js_input;
    }
  </script>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="link" href="" id="title"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="title">
  Bookmarklet Maker
  <br>
  <br>
  <input size="13" name="getTitle" type="text" id="getTitle" style="background-color: #252525;  border: 2px;  border-style: double;  border-color: white;  color: white;  padding: 15px 32px;  text-align: left;  text-decoration: none;  display: inline-block;  font-size: 16px;  font-weight: bold;  margin: 4px 2px;  cursor:;"
    placeholder="Bookmarklet name" />
  <br>
  <input size="40" name="geJs" type="text" id="getJs" style="background-color: #252525;  border: 2px;  border-style: double;  border-color: white;  color: white;  padding: 15px 32px;  text-align: left;  text-decoration: none;  display: inline-block;  font-size: 16px;  font-weight: bold;  margin: 4px 2px;  cursor:;"
    placeholder="Javascript" />
  <br>
  <button style="background-color: #252525;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;" id="bookmarkletbutton" onclick="createBookmarklet()">Create</button>
  <script>
    function createBookmarklet() {
      var title_input = document.getElementById('getTitle').value;
      var js_input = document.getElementById('getJs').value;
      document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title_input;
      document.getElementById('title').href = js_input;
    }
  </script>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a class="link" href="" id="title"></a>
</div>
```

You were using the wrong id in getElementById in the last line. Also, use .href for changing href value. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `href` atrubite via `<element>.setAttribute("href", <value>)`
-> `document.getElementById("title").setAttribute("href", js_input)`
(As mentioned by David: `<element>.title = <value>` also works)

Comment: Which can be done easier by just assigning a value to the attribute: `document.getElementById("title").href = js_input`. However – upvoted :)